# Mongodb ordered option doesn't work when using insertMany method in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using Mongodb in my app. It is version **4.4.1**. I have set unique option in the word field to true.

And I use this code:

```js
try {
    const words = [
      { word: "her" },
      { word: "her" },
      { word: "gathered" },
      { word: "together" },
      { word: "and" },
      { word: "rather" },
    ];

    const result = await wordsDb
      .collection
      .insertMany(words, { ordered: false });

    console.log(result.insertedCount); // nothing to console
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message); // E11000 duplicate key error index: word_1 dup key: { word: "her" }
  }
```

It still gives the "duplicate key error". Why is it happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a `unique` constraint in the `word` field, you cannot insert in the collection 2 documents with the same value ('her') for the `word` field.

And you cannot bypass the constraint with the `{ordered: true}`  option.

Indeed, throwing the error doesn't mean that other documents are not inserted. Did u check if they were inserted? If I try with an example similar to yours (not in Node but in *[MongoDb Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass)*), I get the error too, **but** the documents are all inserted in the collection (except for the one with the duplicate key, obviously, that is inserted only once).

Also, consider that the **insert error** thrown causes the code to jump immediately to the `catch(error)` block, so your `console.log(result.insertedCount)` can not be showed.

Comment: I know. Please take a look this [this](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#insertMany). Mongodb says "
If ordered true, when an insert fails, don't execute the remaining writes. If false, continue with remaining inserts when one fails."

Comment: Consider that error being thrown doesn't exclude that other documents are indeed inserted. Did u check it? (I also **edited a bit my answer**)

Comment: Ah! Sorry. You are right! Thanks dude. Seeing the error misled me. It was already working perfectly.